# Trying to retrieve just one node value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i have these two files:

Ej1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="prue1.xslt"?>
<isa:ISAApplication xmlns:isa="http://xxxx">
    <refId>olatesting</refId>
    <refId2>olatesting2</refId2>
</isa:ISAApplication>
```

prue1.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ISAApplication">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:value-of select="/refId"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Im trying just to retrieve the first "refId", but it is displaying both like this:

olatestingolatesting2

How can i get just "olatesting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `isa` namespace to the stylesheet-declaration and to add the prefix to the template match-pattern, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:isa="http://xxxx" version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="isa">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="isa:ISAApplication">
    <xsl:value-of select="refId"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns

```
olatesting
```

As side information - previously, your template didn't match the input XML at all because of the missing namespace - even if you would remove the template from the XSL you would still get both values  of the input XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"  encoding="utf-8"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML returns

```
olatesting
olatesting2
```

but this may depend on the XSLT processor used (tested with Saxon and Xalan).